# What is the difference between Thirunadu and Paramapadam in Sri Vaishnavism?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, moksha, vaikuntha

The famous Sri Vaishnava Acharya Ramanujacharya was once asked by his shishya Vangipuram Nambi what the obstacles to Moksha are. In response, he gave a list of 83 obstacles to Moksha, known as the [Virodhi Pariharam](http://mannaram.tripod.com/ramanuja/pdfs/virodhpe.pdf). The 58th item on the list is "Ukti Virodhi", which means "speech is an obstacle".  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Ii2.jpg) are some of the types of speech which Vangipuram Nambi lists as falling under this obstacle:

> Referring to those who reached Thiruvadi as merely dead, referring to those who reached Paramapada as those who reached Thiruvadi, **referring to those who reached Thirunadu as having gone to Paramapadam**, not referring to persons devoted in the pride of Acharya as having reached Acharyan Thiruvadi.

Let me explain what this means.  Sri Vaishnavas believe that attaining Moksha involves going to Vishnu’s supreme abode of Paramapadam (aka Vaikuntha).  There the soul will have Sayujya or equality of experience with Brahman.  It will have the same infinite bliss that Sriman Narayana has, and as an outpouring of that bliss it will engage in Nitya Kainkaryam or eternal service to the Thiruvadi or holy feet of Sriman Narayana.  And, if the soul was extremely devoted to a Sri Vaishnava Acharya while it was alive, then in Paramapadam it will perform service to the Acharyan Thiruvadi, i.e. the holy feet of the Acharya.

So Vangipuram Nambi says you shouldn’t refer to those who attained Paramapadam as merely those who have died, you shouldn’t refer to those who have gone to Paramapadam as those who have attained the Thiruvadi of Sriman Narayana, and you shouldn’t referred to those who have attained Acharyan Thiruvadi as those who have attained the Thiruvadi of Sriman Narayana.

But my question is, why does Vangipuram Nambi say you shouldn’t refer to those who have attained Thirunadu as those who have attained Paramapadam?  Thirunadu is Tamil for “holy country”, and it’s usually used as a synonym for Paramapadam.  But is there some subtle distinction between the terms Thirunadu and Paramapadam, such that we can distinguish between people who attained one rather than the other?

Comment: @UdayKrishna Paadam is foot, not Padam.  Paramapadam means "supreme abode" or "supreme state".

Comment: @UdayKrishna As I said, that’s the meaning of Paada, not Pada.

Comment: Is this really such a serious obstacle? Like why would anyone be denied Moksha for calling a person who reached Thiruvadi as a person who reached Paramapadam? How is that a Mukti Virodhi?